# 'audioplayers/AudioplayersPlugin.h' file not found in flutter

Tags: ios, swift, audio, dart, flutter

Unable to use audio in flutter for ios development

This is my code :
pubspec.yaml (using audioplayers: ^0.7.8 plugin for playing audio)

```
name: play_audio
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  # lib for adding sound
  audioplayers: ^0.7.8

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/sound/correct_answer.mp3
    - assets/sound/wrong_answer.mp3
```

play_audio.dart file
Importing audio_cache.dart file to play the audio. I have imported the audio files in assets folder of the project.
The same code works fine in the android devices

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

// audio file path
const correctSoundPath = "sound/correct_answer.mp3";
const inCorrectSoundPath = "sound/wrong_answer.mp3";

class PlayAudio extends StatefulWidget {
  _PlayAudioState createState() => _PlayAudioState();
}

class _PlayAudioState extends State<PlayAudio> {
  AudioCache player;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    player = AudioCache(); // initialising audio cache
    debugPrint("inside initState");
  }

  Future _playCorrect() async {
    player.play(correctSoundPath);
    debugPrint("inside _playCorrect()");
  }

  Future _playIncorrect() async {
    player.play(inCorrectSoundPath);
    debugPrint("inside _playIncorrect()");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          // correct button
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text("Correct"),
            onPressed: () {
              _playCorrect();
            },
          ),

          // incorrect button
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text("Incorrect"),
            onPressed: () {
              _playIncorrect();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Getting the following error while running this project in iOS device using flutter run :

```
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:

    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    Debug.xcconfig line 1: Unable to find included file "Pods/Target Support
    Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
    Debug.xcconfig line 1: Unable to find included file "Pods/Target Support
    Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/quiz/Documents/Project/Flutter_Project/TODO_Flutter_Projects/Quiz/multiple_choice_ios/ios/Runner/Genera
    tedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'audioplayers/AudioplayersPlugin.h' file not found
    #import <audioplayers/AudioplayersPlugin.h>
```

The above code run proper without using audio file. If there is something that i am missing to add, please tell me, and I am using Microsoft visual Studio Code as my IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue too and just needed to install CocoaPods.

```
brew install cocoapods
pod setup
```

There's an error that indicates you need to do this, but it's buried in the build output.

Comment: I tried the above command, but getting the error message pod setup command not working. If you get this error, then in Mac open terminal and type: rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos then type pod setup command